# Weird behavior/error trying to use HAProxy to forward requests to ELBs

Tags: ssl, haproxy, amazon-elb

We have an architecture where have several APIs on multiple hosts. Each API sits behind an AWS ELB. We want to put a proxy in front that will route requests based on URI to the ELB.

What I have so far mostly works, but about 3 out of 10 requests result in the following error (using cURL, but the problem isn't cURL):

```
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to test-router.versal.com:-9847
```

I have a feeling that the ELB is the culprit. The SSL is terminated there.

Here is our HAProxy config:

```
global
  log 127.0.0.1   local0
  log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
  maxconn 10240
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  daemon
  debug
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock
  log-send-hostname test-router.domain.com
  description "HAProxy on test-router.domain.com"

defaults
  log     global
  mode    http
  option  httplog
  option  dontlognull
  retries 3
  option redispatch
  option forwardfor
  option httpclose
  option dontlognull
  option tcpka
  maxconn 10240
  timeout connect 10000ms
  timeout client 600000ms
  timeout server 600000ms

frontend public
  bind *:80
  bind *:443
  acl elb0 path_beg /elb0
  acl elb1 path_beg /elb1
  use_backend elb0 if elb0
  use_backend elb1 if elb1

  bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/cert.pem no-sslv3 ciphers AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH

backend elb0
  server server_vcat elb0.domain.com:443 ssl verify none

backend elb1
  server server_laapi elb1.domain.com:443 ssl verify none
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSL from curl is *not* terminated at the ELB.  It is terminated at HAProxy, in your configuration...

```
bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/cert.pem no-sslv3 ciphers AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH
```

...and then an entirely different SSL session is established by HAProxy on the connection to the ELB:

```
server ... ssl verify none
```

An SSL problem with ELB could not possibly be propagated back to curl through HAProxy in this configuration.

The problem is in your HAProxy configuration, here:

```
bind *:443
```

Remove that line. It's redundant (and incorrect).

You are telling HAProxy to bind to port 443 twice: once speaking SSL, and once *not* speaking SSL.

So, statistically, on approximately 50% of your connection attempts, curl finds HAProxy is not speaking SSL on port 443 -- it's just speaking HTTP, and curl can't (and shouldn't) handle that gracefully.

I believe this (mis)configuration goes undetected by HAProxy, not because of an actual bug, but rather because of the way some things are implemented in the HAProxy internals, related to multi-process deployments and hot reloads, in which case it would be valid to have HAProxy bound to the same socket more than once.

Comment: Of course, it's obvious now. The one line I never considered. Thank you so very much. Your answer is priceless.